# Reading a BLE Characteristic Value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I need some help. After 5 years, I am trying to program in swift again and I am struggling on one point.
I have an arduino device which is sending this data

```
typedef struct {
  byte  deviceid[8];
  float temperature;
  float wind;
  float pressure;
} DataPacket;
```

it comes to my swift app and I can see the 20 bytes of data in characteristic.value.

I created the same structure in swift as

```
struct ArduinoData {
   var deviceid = Array(repeating: 0, count: 8)
   var temperature: Float
   var wind: Float
   var pressure: Float
}
```

How can I assign the incoming data to this struct. Tried some work with UnsafeRawPointer, but did not manage. May be someone can show me a small code fracture for this.
Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by asking chatGPT

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    guard let data = characteristic.value else {
        print("Received data is nil")
        return
    }

    let byteBuffer = [UInt8](data)
    
    if byteBuffer.count < 20 {
        print("Received data is too short")
        return
    }
    
    // Create a DataPacket struct and parse the bytes
    var packet = DataPacket(
        deviceID: Array(byteBuffer[0..<8]),
        temperature: Float(bitPattern: UInt32(bitPattern: Int32(littleEndian: Data(byteBuffer[8..<12]).withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Int32.self) }))),
        wind: Float(bitPattern: UInt32(bitPattern: Int32(littleEndian: Data(byteBuffer[12..<16]).withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Int32.self) }))),
        pressure: Float(bitPattern: UInt32(bitPattern: Int32(littleEndian: Data(byteBuffer[16..<20]).withUnsafeBytes { $0.load(as: Int32.self) })))
    )
    
    // Now, 'packet' contains the parsed data
    //print("Device ID: \(packet.deviceID)")
    print("Temperature: \(packet.temperature)")
    print("Wind: \(packet.wind)")
    print("Pressure: \(packet.pressure)")
}
```

}

Comment: Be aware that ChatGPT answers are not permitted

Comment: Have you tested this solution? I'm skeptical that the floats are encoded in little-endian byte order.

Comment: I tested and it is working. ChatGPT‘s solution was with BigEndian and it did not function, I have alreqdy an Android app running and there I used little endian and it was working so I tried with little and voila, also funtioned for swift